Can I represent concepts like disjoint directly using GeoSPARQL?
Can I represent that a georegion is disjoint (the exact inverse) from another using GeoSPARQL?
I want to represent (in RDF using my own ontology along with GeoSPARQL) that I have an entity inside some area which is completely disjoint to some other area. E.g. I want to describe when a car exits my suburb (or enters "not my suburb").
I tried to do this by using the geosparql sfDisjoint predicate to represent the location covering the entire earth that is "not my suburb". That didn't work at SPARQL query time because sfDisjoint is rightly treated as a function, not a relationship/property by the query engine.
I'm conscious that I'm not articulating this well. Does anyone understand my problem enough to help me describe it better?
Even better, does anyone understand if I can use GeoSPARQL to actually represent the fact that some location is disjoint rather than merely calculate whether it is as a query result. If not, is there a more appropriate ontology to use to represent such spatial relationships.
# Purely illustrative Turtle RDF sample showing how I've tried to use geosparql:sfDisjoint predicate.

@prefix data: <http://somedata.doesnt.matter.what#> .
@prefix ont: <http://someontologydoesnt.matter.what#> .
@prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> .

# Car 1 is in my suburb
data:mycar1 a ont:Car ;
    ont:inLocation data:mysuburb .

# Car 2 is outside my suburb
data:mycar2 a ont:Car ;
    ont:inLocation [ 
        a ont:Location ;
        geo:sfDisjoint data:mysuburb
    ] .

data:mysuburb a ont:Location ;
    ont:name "My Suburb" ;
    ont:geoJSON """{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[40,40], [40,41], [41,40], [40,40]]]}""" .

Note: Crossposted on GIS stack exchange https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/487352/how-to-represent-that-region-is-disjoint-the-exact-inverse-from-another-using but I think I chose the wrong exchange.

not sure if I understand, so to clarify what does not work when you use the sfDisjoint property in a triple? I mean, I know this object property might be interpreted as "magic predicate" during querying when the query rewrite extension is activated. But that should not prevent your from using the property as is. It's part of the GeoSPARQL ontology, so it does belong to the vocabulary : https://opengeospatial.github.io/ogc-geosparql/geosparql11/geo.html#sfDisjoint

Indeed, GeoSPARQL itself does only work on spatial objects contained in your dataset, so it won't give you any GeoJSON object serialization that makes the "rest of the earth" minus your suburb. But I guess that's what you didn't expect anyways? So what is you use-case once you have your data? How do you use it?

@UninformedUser You have understood perfectly. The use case is merely to represent at this point. Downstream users can do with it whatever they want. So if they know car A has left the suburb that has meaning and they do something with it. The possible inferences machines might make with the data are infinite. My job is just to represent it unambiguously using the best ontology there is for it!

We don't experience any problems until query time. When we go to query on the data, the sfDisjoint predicate is treated in a special way by the SPARQL parser and so the WHERE clause doesn't work properly. It thinks there are no matches where there are!

The answer, which came from one of the contributors to GeoSPARQL outside this forum, is that GeoSPARQL ontology geo:sfDisjoint property/relationship is an appropriate way to represent geometric/spatial disjointness.
This is in the GeoSPARQL spec at section 9.2: https://docs.ogc.org/is/22-047r1/22-047r1.html#_dc9619d5-0ced-45ad-92a8-7390c6daea62
The GeoSPARQL query functions are similarly named but exist in a different namespace and are not meant to be used for representation. The geof:sfDisjoint function is covered in section 11.2 of the spec: https://docs.ogc.org/is/22-047r1/22-047r1.html#_b199579b-ac9d-4a2c-9df8-82325eba9660
The original question was raised due to unexpected behaviour within Jena with GeoSPARQL packages included. When executing a query where the representation included geo:sfDisjoint the query result would be incorrectly empty. This appears to be a bug/error with the Jena GeoSPARQL packages, not any issue with the GeoSPARQL spec.
